# Jquery to execute code if a descendant of an element contains a particular word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div id="firstpanel">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td class="alert alert-error">
                <span class="errorMsg">Required:</span>
                blah blah
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="second panel">
    some text
</div>
```

I want to execute some code if the firstpanel div contains the word "Required"

The following code doesn't work for me:

```
if($("#firstpanel").contains("Required")){

      //some code


 }
```

Comment: Try `if( $('#firstpanel:contains("Required")').length ) { .... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector

```
if($('#firstpanel:contains("Required")').length){

      //some code

}
```

> **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**  : The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof. As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks. The text must have matching case to be selected.  ( Taken from https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ )

Answer (score 2):

You use `contains` **function** if you want to find an ***element***

If you want to find if a certain string appears inside the element then use:
`:contains()` **selector**

`if($('#firstpanel:contains("Required")').length){}`

Answer (score 0):

This worked too:

```
if ($("#firstpanel").text().match("Required")) {
//somecode
}
```